# MySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with two fields

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

**My table:**

```
----------------------------
| valueA | valueB | valueC |
----------------------------
|  ...   |  ...   |  ...   |
|  ...   |  ...   |  ...   |
```

- The primary key is (valueA, valueB)
- I want to insert the values or update valueC if the entry already exists

**My code:**

```
INSERT INTO myTable (valueA, valueB, valueC) VALUES
(1, 2, 1), 
(1, 2, 2),
(2, 1, 3), 
(3, 4, 4)
on duplicate key update valueC = 5;
```

**Result of that statement:**

```
----------------------------
| valueA | valueB | valueC |
----------------------------
|   1    |   2    |   5    |
|   2    |   1    |   3    |
|   3    |   4    |   4    |
```

I don't just want to update if the new valueA = old valueA and the new valueB = old valueB but also if the new valueA = old valueB and the new valueB = old valueA.

In my example table (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2) and (2, 1, 3) would be duplicates. Not just (1, 2, 1) and (1, 2, 2).

**This is how it should look like:**

```
----------------------------
| valueA | valueB | valueC |
----------------------------
|   1    |   2    |   5    |
|   3    |   4    |   4    |
```

How can I do this with as few statements as possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD COLUMN least_value INT AS ((LEAST(valueA, valueB))),
    ADD COLUMN greatest_value INT AS ((GREATEST(valueA, valueB))),
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (least_value, greatest_value);
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wX8SkzxdfFzXqMKViWe77S/0)

---

> what would you do if the values were strings? – Colin

`LEAST`/`GREATEST` functions processes string values correctly. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wX8SkzxdfFzXqMKViWe77S/1). The only thing - the datatype for calculated column must be able to accept the value.

Comment: That's a cool solution, thanks. Just out of curiosity ... what would you do if the values were strings?

Comment: Found a solution for that. I can order the values alphabetically in PHP before inserting them into the db.

Comment: @Colin Updated.